# Плавающий компонент c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Пытаюсь сделать плавающую панельку или кнопку, при нажатии скрола на форме всё работает, но при скроле подглючивает.
Привязывался к AutoScrollPosition.Y

Comment: что значит "подглючивает" и поверх чего должна плавать панелька?

Comment: @rdorn подглючивает в плане иногда передвигается, иногда нет, а разница то поверх чего? а вообще просто на форме

Comment: ну тогда разместите панель прямо на форме закрепив положение и размер, а остальной контент пусть меняется под ней, хоть скролом, хоть чем. Через конструктор форм это не сделать а в коде запросто. указав в свойстве Parrent форму

Comment: или подпишитесь на событие мыши связанное с колесиком, не помню как называется, но подглючивает потому, скорее всего, что вы подписались на события скрола формы, а на события колесика мыши не подписались, вот оно и не реагирует